# if $AC=B$ and if two of these matrices are invertible then show the third matrix is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

if $AC=B$  and if two of these matrices are invertible then the third matrix is invertible +

Direct Proof:

let's assume $A$ and $C$ are invertible:

$$AC = B$$

$$(AC)(AC)^{-1} = B(AC)^{-1} $$

$$(B)(AC)^{-1} = B(AC)^{-1} $$

however, I don't know how to continue the proof

Comment: If $A$ is invertible then $A^{-1}$ actually exists, so you can use it.  So, use it.

Comment: To prove that $B$ is invertible you just need to solve the equation $BX=Id$ which is $BX=ACX=Id$ this should help!

Comment: @marilou64 does this poof all of the possible sets of permutations for which of the 2 matrices are invertible?

Comment: @marilou64 are you using the fact that we are trying to prove?

Comment: @Randall I am using it

Comment: I see what you mean, I've read your post incorrectly, this works for only one case but since there is only three cases you can deal with them separately and use the same idea

Comment: Just do each case separately, no need to do all three at once

Comment: my question is why we can use $BX=I$ is not that what we are trying proof?

Comment: @samsamradas  You're not, because $A^{-1}$ never appears by itself in your "proof."

Comment: Yes but since the definition of being invertible is : $B$ invertible if there exist $X$ another matrix such that $BX=XB=Id$ then if you find such a $X$ then you've shown that $B$ is invertible.

Comment: Then when you have found this $X$ you can simply write your proof by beginning like that: Consider the matrix $X$ ( $X$ will have a precise form that you found doing calculation on your own) then you show that $BX=Id$ doing your calculation the other way around

Comment: @marilou64 I would like to see you post an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's do one case: $A,C$ invertible then there exist $A^{-1}$ and $C^{-1}$ the inverse of $A$ and $C$.

Now you do some writting on the corner of a paper: our goal is to find the inverse of $B$ so let's see how it would look if this inverse exist:
Let $X$ be such that $BX=Id$. Then :
$$Id=BX=ACX \iff A^{-1}=CX \iff C^{-1}A^{-1}=X$$

Well since we know that  $A^{-1}$ and $C^{-1}$ exists by our assumption we can write our proof:

Let's consider the matrix $X=C^{-1}A^{-1}$ then we see that :
$$BX=BC^{-1}A^{-1}=ACC^{-1}A^{-1}=AA^{-1}=Id$$
So $X$ is the inverse of $B$ which mean that $B$ is invertible.

Sometimes when you want to show that an object exist, you can say it does and try to find how it would looks!

Comment: are you sure we can use that fact?

Comment: Which fact ?????

Comment: $$Id =BX  $$   I am used up to use the premise to reach the implication

Comment: I understand your confusion, the part where I said that you do some writing on the corner of your page is not part of the proof. It's just here to help us understand why we should set $X=A^{-1}C^{-1}$

Comment: If I would have just written the last part starting at "Let's consider ..." you would have been ok with my proof ?

Comment: I get your confusion, math can be confusing, but this is a "technique" that is often used !

Comment: in 
"Lets consider " you are also using $BX$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150358/discussion-between-marilou64-and-samsamradas).

Comment: your method is called proof by construction